# How to create and filter related model objects in django application

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, foreign-keys, formset

I am building a testing application and I need to run through a series of test steps. I have a few questions surrounding the concern of mine.

1. When you create a test, you will select wether it will be a full or partial test. A full test will run through all the test steps. A partial test will be able to go a individual step.

When a full test is created then all the test steps should be created by default.

2. How will I filter the test steps when a user selects a partial test?
3. In my test-detail template, I need to go through a series of questions which will be forms that send requests and recieve responses from an api.
   I am wondering how i can use a form set or another way to pass on to the next form. For example, step 1 - do whatever it says, click next. Next will be the form submit which will send the request and the next form will populate the django template.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

View.py

```
def create_test(request, id=None):
    form = PrinterTestForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.printer = Printer.objects.get(id=id)
        instance.save()
        # test = Test.objects.get_object_or_404(Test, id=instance.id)
        return redirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        test_name = None
        test_type = None
        test = None


    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "testing/create_test.html", context)

def test_detail(request, id):
    test_instance = get_object_or_404(Test, id=id)
    printer_status_check = printer_check(test_instance)

    stepOne = 
    context = {
        "test": test_instance,
        'printer_status': printer_status_check
    }
    return render(request, "testing/test_detail.html", context)


def printer_check(request):
    device_dns = request.printer.device_dns
    status = get_status_test(device_dns)
    return status
```

models.py

```
TESTCHOICES = (
    ('Full Test', 'full_test'),
    ('Partial Test', 'partial_test')
)

TEST_REGEX = '^[a-zA-Z0-9.+-_ ]*$'

class Test(models.Model):
    test_name           = models.CharField(max_length=120, validators=[RegexValidator(regex=TEST_REGEX, message="Only Alphanumeric characters allowed in Test Name", code="invalid_test_name")])
    test_type           = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=TESTCHOICES, default='Full Test')
    printer             = models.ForeignKey(Printer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.test_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('testing:test_detail', kwargs={'id': self.id })


class TestStep(models.Model):
    test                = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test_type_step      = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=TESTCHOICES)
    test_step_name      = models.CharField(max_length=240)
```

Comment: Another question I have is if I am even right with having TestStep have Test as a foreign key. I saw one person had questionaire and question as a many to many?

Comment: Can I create a test step view for all the test steps? Or will i have to create a view for each?

Comment: This is not the place for design help. It is for code solutions.

Comment: This above is code. And I am looking for a solution to have 17 test steps with a test if the full test is selected. In my view, I am trying to figure out how to create these test steps if full test is selected when the test model object is created.

Comment: You should probably create your test in a different file and then call it from your view.

Comment: What? why would i do that

Comment: Here's the reference for [filtering models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/). This is way to vague to figure out what you are trying to do. Please see stacks [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).